# How can I determine what image shows up based on your time zone or local time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have no acess to php. Is this possible w/ jquery?
Here is an example.
lets say the business opens at 11:00am and closes at 7:00 and the would like for a live chat image to say 'we're online!' but when they're closed they want the image to say 'we're offline'.
Does this help? If anyone has a solution to this please help. thanks.

Comment: I' used this script that @ConfinedSpace answered w/ I like it - its straightforward and helpful. Just one question for you jquery, javascript ninjas - is this based off the user's time?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var objDate = new Date();
var hours = objDate.getHours();
var imgsrc = (hours > 11 && hours < 19) ? 'open.jpg' : 'close.jpg';
document.write('<img src="'+imgsrc+'" />');
//-->
</script>
how can i use this to an id or class - so when its 5:00 pm the id or class on the image is changed to close. 
for ex. <img src="open.jpg" id="chat"> when it hits 5:00pm the #chat image switches to close.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to compensate for other timezones using Central Standard Time as the server's timezone:

http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/AcFhg/2/

javascript/jQuery:

```
// Translate your hours to UTC, example here is using Central Standard Time (-0500 UTC)
// Opening hour in UTC is 16, Closing hour is 0 the next day
var d = new Date(), 
    open = new Date(), 
    closed = new Date();

// Statically set UTC date for open
open.setUTCHours(16); // Open time at 11:00 am CST which is 16:00 UTC
open.setUTCMinutes(0);
open.setUTCSeconds(0);
open.setUTCMilliseconds(0);

// Statically Set UTC date for closing
closed.setUTCDate(d.getUTCDate()+1); // UTC time rotates back to 0 so we add a day
closed.setUTCHours(0); // Closing time at 7:00 pm CST which is 00:00 UTC (so we need to add a day)
closed.setUTCMinutes(0);
closed.setUTCSeconds(0);
closed.setUTCMilliseconds(0);

// Debugging
console.log("user's date:" + d);
console.log("store open time in user's timezone:" + open);
console.log("store close time in user's timezone:" + closed);
console.log(d > open); // user's time is greater than opening time
console.log(d < closed); // is user's time less than closing time (you don't have to go home...)

// Test for store open?
if (d > open && d < closed) {
    setOpenStatus(true);
}
else {
    setOpenStatus(false);
}

function setOpenStatus(isOpen) {
    $('#open').toggle(isOpen);
    $('#closed').toggle(!isOpen);
}
```

Note: it would be really difficult to fully compensate for the various daylight savings changes around the world but this will work for most cases

Comment: Sweet! This is awesome! So lets say they want to open - monday through friday from 9AM-5PM in a pacific time zone and saturday and sunday closed? Is this possible using the script above?

Comment: using the Date object's [getDay()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getday.asp) method, change the if to something like `if (d.getDay() !== 0 && d.getDay() !== 6 && (d > open && d < closed)` to factor in Saturday and Sunday

Comment: Do you have an email address i can contact you directly? I appreciate your help! I have a few more questions if your willing to answer. I tried implementing what you suggested but I'm having a hard time trying to get it to work as I'm not that familiar with JS syntax.

Comment: I'd prefer you make any subsequent questions available to the SO community.  Keep asking via comments or compose a new question with where you were stuck after starting to use the above javascript.

Comment: i used the code snippet that you mentioned in your second comment but it doesn't work for me - for example:
'code'
// Test for store open?
if (d.getDay() !== 0 && d.getDay() !== 6 && (d > open && d < closed)

else {
    setOpenStatus(false);
}

function setOpenStatus(isOpen) {
    $('#open').toggle(isOpen);
    $('#closed').toggle(!isOpen);
}

what am i doing wrong? and what if i want to adjust the time to PST 9am-5pm and closed saturday and sunday? Sorry if I'm being a pain. You are very helpful! Wish there was a way i can compensate you.. Let me know if there is a way i can.

Comment: Looks like it was missing a closing parenthesis at the end should be `...d < closed))`

Comment: Another question! sorry for being a pain! I adjusted the time to 0 but somehow it returns my image to closed -
what i want to adjust is to say open at 9AM and close at 5PM - PST Time I have adjusted the opening time correct - however when i adjust +1 to zero it doesn't work please see how i changed it below. can you help? thanks 
--->closed.setUTCDate(d.getUTCDate(0)); <--- also when i do this my console says -true for the opening time and false for the close time - hope this helps

Comment: closing time for 5 PM PST = 1 AM the next day UTC, you should be able to leave `closed.setUTCDate(d.getUTCDate() + 1);` and instead change `closed.setUTCHours(0);` to `closed.setUTCHours(1);`

Answer (score 2):

You could get the client date using the [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object and [datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) to simplify date manipulations like parsing, ...

Comment: Won't that only really be useful and correct if the server and client are both in the same timezone as the business?

Comment: @RwL: Clearly you'd store the business opening times w.r.t. a given timezone.

Comment: Yeah, I can see that, but I was thinking (as I'm based in the US) that if you did that you'd still be off by an hour during daylight savings, no? I don't understand UTC time well (yet; off to Wikipedia I go) so I'm not seeing how that's accounted for at all in the posted solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
var today = new Date();
var h     = today.getHours();
var m     = today.getMinutes();
var s     = today.getSeconds();

if ((h > 18) || (h < 11)) {
   $(img).src('closed.jpg');
}
```

Comment: Breaks when the client and business are in different timezones, and your conditional can _never_ be true. You probably meant `||`, not `&&`.

Comment: Speed error, indeed meant ||. If it's a local business I'd assume the timezone wouldn't be an issue. If it is then timezones should clearly be taken into account as well.

Comment: What is a "local business" on the internet?

Comment: A business close by. The internet is not location-less. Ppl that would be interested in Madison's pub in toronto, would also most likely reside in toronto

Answer (score 1):

As multiple people have pointed out, anything you do on the client machine will be based on the client time rather than your actual business time.

Why don't you put an image on the page, don't worry about changing anything on the page, and just change the image on your server when your business opens or closes?

Comment: but i would have to do this daily. this is what i want to avoid.

Comment: @Stuart: Can't you *automate* it?

Comment: not sure but the above script worked - i'm very pleased on how it is written.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var objDate = new Date();
var hours = objDate.getHours();
var imgsrc = (hours > 11 && hours < 19) ? 'open.jpg' : 'close.jpg';
document.write('<img src="'+imgsrc+'" />');
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: is this based on the user's time zone or the server?

Comment: I would recommend you check Date.js ... This is an amazing library you can use when working with dates : http://www.datejs.com/ I know this is not the answer you're looking for, but I *believe* you gonna find this useful.

Comment: ok - im not a javascript expert. but what is the top script actually doing? is it based on the users time?

Answer (score -1):

hopefully following can help you a bit

http://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_if_else.asp

Comment: I doubt a tutorial from an awful resource about if-else statements is quite what the OP had in mind when he posted this question.