# How to determine the image that is displayed during business hours/days?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I already asked this question before and I received the following as an answer which truly helps! However lets say the business opens at **9:00 AM** and closes at **5:00 PM** *PST time (California)* and they are closed on Saturday and Sunday.

How can I adjust that below?

Also keep in mind that the script below is triggering an image to show/display/hide based on the business hours. So at **9:00 AM PST** time the image say's 'We're Open' and at **5:00 PM** the image then goes to 'We're Closed'. Thanks guys I hope I have entered enough data/information for you to answer this question.

Here is a reference [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/AcFhg/2/).

```
$(window).load(function(){
  // Translate your hours to UTC, example here is using
  // Central Standard Time (-0500 UTC)

  // Opening hour in UTC is 16, Closing hour is 0 the next day
  var d      = new Date(), 
      open   = new Date(), 
      closed = new Date();

  // Statically set UTC date for open
  open.setUTCHours(16);
  open.setUTCMinutes(0);
  open.setUTCSeconds(0);
  open.setUTCMilliseconds(0);

  // Statically Set UTC date for closing
  closed.setUTCDate(d.getUTCDate()+1); // UTC time rotates back to 0, add a day
  closed.setUTCHours(0); // UTC hours is 0
  closed.setUTCMinutes(0);
  closed.setUTCSeconds(0);
  closed.setUTCMilliseconds(0);

  // Debugging
  console.log("user's date:" + d);
  console.log("store open time in user's timezone:" + open);
  console.log("store close time in user's timezone:" + closed);
  console.log(d > open); // user's time is greater than opening time
  console.log(d < closed); // is user's time less than closing time
                           // (you don't have to go home...)

  // Test for store open?
  if (d > open && d < closed) {
    setOpenStatus(true);
  } else {
    setOpenStatus(false);
  }

  function setOpenStatus(isOpen) {
    $('#opend').toggle(isOpen);
    $('#closed').toggle(!isOpen);
  }
});​
```

---

**EDITED/UPDATED SCRIPT**

```
$(window).load(function(){
  // Translate your hours to UTC, example here is using
  // Central Standard Time (-0500 UTC)

  // Opening hour in UTC is 16, Closing hour is 0 the next day
  var d      = new Date(), 
      open   = new Date(), 
      closed = new Date();

  // Statically set UTC date for open
  open.setUTCHours(16);
  open.setUTCMinutes(0);
  open.setUTCSeconds(0);
  open.setUTCMilliseconds(0);

  // Statically Set UTC date for closing
  closed.setUTCDate(d.getUTCDate()+1); // UTC time rotates back to 0, add a day
  closed.setUTCHours(0); // UTC hours is 0
  closed.setUTCMinutes(0);
  closed.setUTCSeconds(0);
  closed.setUTCMilliseconds(0);

  // Debugging
  console.log("user's date:" + d);
  console.log("store open time in user's timezone:" + open);
  console.log("store close time in user's timezone:" + closed);
  console.log(d > open); // user's time is greater than opening time
  console.log(d < closed); // is user's time less than closing time
                           // (you don't have to go home...)

  // Test for store open?
  if (d > open && d < closed) {
    setOpenStatus(true);
  }
  if (d.getDay() !== 0 && d.getDay() !== 6 && (d > open && d < closed))
  else {
    setOpenStatus(false);
  }

  function setOpenStatus(isOpen) {
    $('#opend').toggle(isOpen);
    $('#closed').toggle(!isOpen);
  }
});​
```

Comment: If you have asked it before, then you should get the small change on that other question: [How can I determine what image shows up based on your time zone or local time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5876282/how-can-i-determine-what-image-shows-up-based-on-your-time-zone-or-local-time)

Comment: Yes but some how it is not working for me. I tried it and I may be doing something wrong - please look at the above code - I cant add my code snippet to this comment area.

Comment: How exactly does it not work?  Wrong times?  What is coming out on the console?

Comment: @orbling: it says it has a syntax error on--> else {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the bottom few lines to this, it is a little muddled at present.

```
if (d.getDay() !== 0 && d.getDay() !== 6 && (d >= open && d < closed)) {
    setOpenStatus(true);
} else {
    setOpenStatus(false);
}
```

So you understand the condition, it says: If it is not Sunday `(d.getDay() !== 0)` or Saturday `(d.getDay() !== 6)` and the current time is after or at the opening time `(d >= open)` and before the closing time `(d < closed)`, then set the open status, otherwise `(else)`, set closed status.

Comment: You sir are amazing!! So I integrated what you suggested and it worked flawlessly. However, just to make sure i Have this right - it says that my business hours are between 9-5am PST and its closed sat. and sunday? I'm not a JS expert that is why I'm asking these questions. Thanks Orbling!

Comment: @Stuart: I did not adjust the times at all, if the example is for CST, then it is still set at that.  Just adjust the UTC times to fit.  UTC is the same as GMT, PST is UTC-8 (note that much of the PST band, if not all switches to PDT in summer, which is UTC-7).

Comment: @Orbling I believe this only works if your working hours fall on the same day in UTC. In the example above, if the working hours extended to 1AM UTC the next day, then a user visiting the page at 12:30AM UTC SATURDAY morning would not be counted correctly(their d.getDay() would be Saturday). This code would tell them the store is closed when it is really the last hour of the day PST on Friday.

Comment: @jamis0n: Correct, I'm not sure why the poster used UTC rather than the local time.  Using weekdays for checking when the definition of the day is not being adhered to will obviously break.  The solution would be to adjust the datetime to the local timezone before getting the day of the week if the local times stick within the day, otherwise it is complicated and requires either using purely the opening time as the day of the week in use and tracking the current date back to the time of day of opening, or setting some arbitrary day boundary, like 6am, instead.