# Auto-updating store opened / store closed being displayed

Tags: javascript, html, css

new to this site. I have searched and searched and kept getting referred back to this previous post - [How to determine the image that is displayed during business hours/days?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887201/can-someone-help-me-adjust-this-script-to-determine-the-image-that-is-displayed)

The previous poster was trying to accomplish the exact thing I am trying to do. I tried the code that was shown in jsfiddle, but I think there is something missing somewhere (in the css?). In fact, in jsfiddle, it shows "store is" and "store is closed" at the same time in the result window. I just can't seem to get it to work no matter what I do.

If they are in fact correct, can someone show me exactly what I need to do / where I need to put these? I just want a small image to be shown if the store is open or closed based on local time.

Any ideas from anyone with some patience would be appreciated. I'd even settle for a configurable widget at this point if anyone knows of one.

Thanks!

Comment: Then show your JS Fiddle implementation; give us *something* to work with.

Comment: I tried the one showed on the post I mentioned..

Comment: Link us to what you currently have.

Comment: Yes, you said you tried it and 'you can't seem to get it to work.' Show us what you tried.

Comment: I saved the javascript shown on jsfiddle (i included the revised ending in post by 'orbling') as "time.js". The css code on jsfiddle doesn't make much sense to me as it starts with "div". Maybe I'm not explaining this right, my apologies. Here's the jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/AcFhg/2/

Answer (score 0):

The fiddle works fine..

it is just that the ***open*** image is not available anymore ..

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/AcFhg/49/) (*different photos that are available..*) and an extra css rule that sets both open/closed divs to be hidden by default.. (*so you do not see the flashing..*)

Comment: How would I add that css code that to my existing css? This is where I am also confused since it starts with "div" and I'm assuming it would change my whole layout if I used it as is.

Comment: can you show us the html/css of your page ? (*perhaps a live link*)

Comment: @skip here is self contained html/css version http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/AcFhg/50/ i just wrapped the html in a div with id `status` and added `#status` to the css rules that required it... this way it will not affect anything outside of itself.. (*do not forget to remove the `console.log` commands from the script as those will choke IE*) .. and btw it looks nice

Comment: Thanks so much for everything and the compliments. I'm by no means a web designer (obviously), I'm just trying to help someone out who paid for a site and it was never finished. Should I remove everything from "// Debugging" to "closing time (you don't have to go home...)"?

Comment: Unfortunately, it still doesn't work. I even tried it on a stripped down sandbox page thinking the javascripts were banging heads somewhere. Is the js code missing something? I noticed on the previous posters post there's a "$(window).load(function(){" at the top of his code but not mine?